# core data: background context ios

Tags: ios, core-data, nsoperation

I already posted this problem and no one tell me what is the problem, please help.

I have problem when I use Core Data to save data in my `iOS` app.

My application can receive many and many text message in a second from a server.

So i need to save those message in my data base, now i use `NSOperations` inside queue to save messages (so you can imagine the number of the `NSOperation` in the `NSOperationQueue`).

The problem is if the i have a normal flow of messages then it works fine and if have an important flow of messages , the app freeze indefinitely or the `NSOperations` increase without limit  in the queue.

**PS: if remove the observer of merge the messages are saved without any problem**

This my code of the `NSOperation`:

```
@interface SaveRecievedMessageOperation()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appdelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL executing;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL finished;

@end

@implementation SaveRecievedMessageOperation

@synthesize message;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize appdelegate;
@synthesize executing;
@synthesize finished;



- (id)initWithMessage:(SipMessage *)messageToSave
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.message = messageToSave;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        self.appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [self managedObjectContext];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                       selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                           object:self.managedObjectContext];

        [self saveMessage];


    }

}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{

    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {

        return managedObjectContext;

    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self.appdelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSOverwriteMergePolicy];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)saveMessage
{

    NSDictionary *header = self.message.headers;

    NSArray *bodies = self.message.bodies;

    SipBody *sipBody;
    NSDictionary* body;
    NSData *ContentData;
    if ([[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"application/json"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        sipBody = [bodies objectAtIndex:0];
        body = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:sipBody.content
                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                error:nil];
    }

    else if ([[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"multipart/mixed"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        for (SipBody *sipB in bodies) {
            if ([[sipB.headers valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"application/json"].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                body = [NSJSONSerialization
                        JSONObjectWithData:sipB.content
                        options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                        error:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                ContentData = [NSData dataWithData:sipB.content];
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return;
    }
    MGMPhone *sender;

    NSArray *senders = [self updatePhonesFromMSISDNsList:[[header valueForKey:@"swfrom"] componentsSeparatedByString:MGMseparator]];
    sender = senders[0];


    NSError *error;
    MGMMessage *aMesage = [MGMMessage createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [aMesage setBoxType:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:BoxTypeIncomingMessage]];
    [aMesage setContent:[body valueForKey:@"Content"]];
    [aMesage setContentType:[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"]];
    [aMesage setGroupMessage:( [[header valueForKey:@"groupmessage"] isEqualToString:@"true"]
                              ?
  [self saveContext];   
}


#pragma mark core data

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];
            [mainContext performSelector:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification];


[self setManagedObjectContext:nil];

}

- (void)saveContext
{


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {

            BOOL isSaved = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if(!isSaved){

                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
        else if (![self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]){
             [self setManagedObjectContext:nil];
        }
    }


  }


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is fine, except the merge operation. I'm using very similar CoreData operations in background myself.

Typically you want to merge updates from background operations with the 'main' managed object context. So basically in the background operation you should only perform the save: method. (So don't register for save notifications nor initiate merge actions).

Unless you really need to merge managed object contexts in background threads, the save notification should be registered only once in the main thread (typically in a singleton e.g. appDelegate or your own singleton). The save notification will be sent by CoreData after any save operation in other contexts, allowing you to merge these changes with the main context.